# How does the clone trooper recognize Darth Sidious to execute Order 66?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

During the film *Star Wars: Revenge the Sith* we see Darth Sidious talking with Commander Cody for the execution of Order 66.

But how does the Commander know that "the dude" with the hoodie was Palpatine? Or did he already know Darth Sidious?

Comment: Related question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151768/how-did-the-clones-know-it-was-palpatine

Comment: @BrootsWaymb more exact duplicate than just related.

Comment: @OrangeDog - I originally commented "Cross-site duplicate: <link>", but some mod or automatic process changed it to that (not sure which, but it wasn't me). Not sure why, because I agree it isn't just "related".

Answer (score 5):

> But how does the Commander know that "the dude" with the hoodie was Palpatine or did he already know Darth Sidious?

## He didn't need to...

Obeying Order 66 was pre-progammed into all clones of which Cody was one.

> Control chips, also known as inhibitor chips, were a type of organic bio-chip capable of dictating or responding to the thoughts of its host. Kaminoan cloners implanted them within each clone trooper in the Grand Army of the Republic. It was implanted into the brain of every trooper at the third stage of their embryonic development. **When they were activated the troopers responded to orders without question**, allowing the Supreme Chancellor to initiate Order 66.
>
> <sup>[**Wookiepedia**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Control_chip)</sup>

So, the Chancellor activated the chips and Cody *had no choice* but to obey.

> As a result of the commander's programming, Cody obeyed the chancellor without hesitation .
>
> <sup>[**Wookiepedia**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CC-2224)</sup>

As detailed in [**Valorum's answer to a similar question on SF&F**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151768/how-did-the-clones-know-it-was-palpatine)

> The film's official novelisation indicates that the frequency was reserved for Palpatine.
>
> > *“Yes, sir.” A silent buzzing vibration came from a compartment> 
> >     concealed within his armor. Cody frowned. “Go on ahead, General. We’ll
> >     be right behind you.”*
> >
> > ***That concealed compartment held a secure comlink, which was
> >     frequency-locked to a channel reserved for the commander in chief.***
> >
> > <sup>[Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup>

Comment: A more canonical source than Wookiepedia would help here, such as a quote from a novel or official sourcebook.

(When the movies first came out, my assumption was that Palpatine was using some Force power on the clone troopers to enforce their loyalty at a distance, which was why he'd had them all cloned from a single individual. But there's no canon justification for that.)

Comment: @Paulie_D by canonical reference we mean an actual primary source that is officially designated as Star Wars canon. Wookiepedia fails on both tests.

Comment: @Paulie_D see [this page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon) for what is and is not Star Wars canon.

Comment: @Paulie_D the page itself is not canon. The text on the page is about what is canon.

Comment: @Paulie_D are you being deliberately obtuse? Quotes from discussions *about* canon are not canon. The official novelization *is* canon. The "alternative source" is the canon itself (i.e. the officially-designated films, books, cartoons, etc.). Wookiepedia, a volunteer-maintained encyclopedia, is not itself part of the Star Wars canon.